# What is this chip and what is it for?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I found a strange 6-pin chip with a barcode and SA20 imprinted on the back of it, The front has a hex shape deeply engraved on it. I looked up the chip online and I couldn't find any information on it. What is this chip and what is it used for?

[image]

Back of the chip.

[image]

Comment: It might help if you added some details about where you found it, IE was it plugged into something, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a 'crash sensor' used to deploy automotive airbags.

Datasheet [here](http://www.sm-elektronik.pl/pdf/SA20.pdf)- made by Sensonor in Norway.

Comment: Can this chip be used for another purpose like putting it inside a ball to detect when it collides with a wall or floor and then sending a wireless signal to make a sound in a loud speaker?

Comment: Looks to me like it's only sensitive in one axis, so I guess you'd need three and some signal conditioning circuitry and a microcontroller/transmitter with ADC.

Comment: How about putting it inside a seat cushion and when some one sits on it, it makes starts to over inflate and a recorded voice from a speaker inside the cushion  says "Get your butt off me"

Comment: It's basically an 50g accelerometer element, which I think would make a lousy butt sensor. A "poorly performing" sensor, just to make that statement 100% clear.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It would make a good HUGE ass sensor. Of course your arse must be massive enough to have a local g of 51 at the surface (assuming we need to cancel out earth gravity).

Comment: @Aron 50g should work for the American market. I'll get a lower g setting for the international market.

Comment: @user148298 just to be clear, the presence of any (all even every) human butt in history would not be enough mass to set off a 50g accelerometer. We need a butt the (literal) size of a huge planet/star to set it off. Even the American market isn't 50x heavier than Earth.

Comment: I have a bag of maybe 50 of these. Are these chips desirable or are they obsolete?